# MySQL search between date, but also between time ranges

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with datetime like this:

```
2018-08-08 00:00:00
2018-08-08 03:00:00
2018-08-08 06:00:00
2018-08-08 09:00:00
2018-08-08 12:00:00
2018-08-08 15:00:00
2018-08-08 18:00:00
2018-08-08 21:00:00
2018-08-09 00:00:00
2018-08-09 03:00:00
2018-08-09 06:00:00
2018-08-09 09:00:00
2018-08-09 12:00:00
```

I search for rows between CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY, but also only at 06:00:00 and 12:00:00.

How can I select this hours?

Regards
Wishy

Comment: Could you put the SQL request you are using in the question?

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `time()` to extract the time.

```
...
WHERE ...
      AND time(nmuloc) BETWEEN time '6:00:00'
                               AND time '12:00:00'
...
```

Comment: In case you need only 6:00 and 12:00, you can use `time(nmuloc) IN ('6:00:00','12:00:00')`.

Comment: @sticky_bit Perfect Solution!! Many thanks! Here my finaly statement: `SELECT `datum`, `wetter`, `temp` FROM `wetter` WHERE `datum` between CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY AND time(`datum`) IN ('6:00:00','12:00:00','18:00:00')`